Two shells on same apptainer instance?
I'm trying to learn to have two shells on the same container with the same overlay. Some googling suggests I want to start an "instance" and then shell into it twice. I've built my image and my overlay with --fakeroot. I'm sharing this server so I'd like to be as unobtrusive to other users as possible.
$ apptainer instance start --fakeroot --overlay my_overlay.img my_image.sif my_new_instance_name
INFO:    User not listed in /etc/subuid, trying root-mapped namespace
INFO:    Using fakeroot command combined with root-mapped namespace
INFO:    Terminating fuse-overlayfs after timeout
INFO:    Timeouts can be caused by a running background process
INFO:    Cleanup error: while stopping driver for /var/lib/apptainer/mnt/session/final: fuse-overlayfs exited: fuse: failed to unmount /var/lib/apptainer/mnt/session/final: Invalid argument
ERROR:   container cleanup failed: no instance found with name my_new_instance_name
FATAL:   container creation failed: while applying cgroups config: unable to start unit "apptainer-2317013.scope" (properties [{Name:Description Value:"libcontainer container 2317013"} {Name:Slice Value:"system.slice"} {Name:Delegate Value:true} {Name:PIDs Value:@au [2317013]} {Name:MemoryAccounting Value:true} {Name:CPUAccounting Value:true} {Name:IOAccounting Value:true} {Name:TasksAccounting Value:true} {Name:DefaultDependencies Value:false}]): Interactive authentication required.

FATAL:   while executing starter: failed to start instance: while running /usr/libexec/apptainer/bin/starter: exit status 255

Not really sure what to make of this error.

I guess key point is : Interactive authentication required. Your config, need add some config to give it a authentication user account and password.

It's a bug in Apptainer. https://github.com/apptainer/apptainer/issues/2189.
==================

The error you're encountering suggests a problem with the apptainer instance starting process due to permission or resource limitations, likely related to fakeroot, cgroups, or the fuse-overlayfs timeout. Here's how you might address the issues:
Key points to address:
User not listed in /etc/subuid: The fakeroot command needs subuid mappings to function correctly.
Timeout in fuse-overlayfs: This can be caused by an issue with the overlay file or something running in the background.
Cgroup issue: The error indicates that the instance creation fails while trying to apply cgroup settings, and it mentions that interactive authentication is required. This could be a permissions issue that needs root or elevated privileges.
Steps to resolve:

Ensure subuid and subgid mappings are set up correctly
Since you're using --fakeroot, Apptainer needs to map your user ID to other sub-user IDs via /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid. If these are not properly set up, you’ll face permission errors. You can request your admin to set this up for you, or if you have access, add entries for your user:

echo "your_username:100000:65536" | sudo tee -a /etc/subuid /etc/subgid

Check if another instance or process is using your overlay
The error about fuse-overlayfs could mean something else is using your overlay file. Try stopping any existing instance using the overlay and ensure it is unmounted:

apptainer instance stop my_new_instance_name
umount /var/lib/apptainer/mnt/session/final
If there’s no active process, manually clean up any lingering files.

Ensure you have sufficient permissions for cgroups
Apptainer may require permission to manage cgroups. If you're running it in a shared environment, you may lack the necessary privileges to do this. You can try asking the admin to add your user to the appropriate cgroup controller, or run your container with fewer resource limits:

apptainer instance start --no-cgroups --fakeroot --overlay my_overlay.img my_image.sif my_new_instance_name

Extend fuse-overlayfs timeout
If the fuse-overlayfs timeout persists, try increasing the timeout value. Add the --timeout flag to the apptainer instance start command. For example:

apptainer instance start --fakeroot --timeout 60 --overlay my_overlay.img my_image.sif my_new_instance_name

Try without fakeroot or ask for sudo access
If fakeroot is causing issues, and you have sufficient privileges, try running the instance without fakeroot, or request temporary sudo access to run Apptainer with root privileges directly.

Double-check the overlay image
Verify that your my_overlay.img is a valid and well-formed overlay that supports the image. You can also try without the overlay to see if the issue lies there:


apptainer instance start --fakeroot my_image.sif my_new_instance_name
Debugging
If none of the above helps, enabling debug logs might give more insight:
apptainer --debug instance start --fakeroot --overlay my_overlay.img my_image.sif my_new_instance_name
try these steps
